# can´t make your two or more methods in same route

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

the link to the project
https://github.com/Kammikazy/project
i can´t make work my get two or more methods in same route
i have the code 404
i using mysql nodejs and express
my code
 controller alliances

```
const User = require('../models/Alliances')

const findAlianca = async (connection,  req, res) => {

  const Allianca = await User.find(connection, req.session.user.username)
  if (!Allianca) {
 res.status(404).send('Nenhuma cidade encontrada.');
 return;
}
console.log("dddd");
          req.session.Allianca = Allianca
          res.locals.Allianca = Allianca
res.render('Administration/Alliances')
  }

  module.exports = {
   findAlianca
  }
```

route aliance

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const connection = require('../../Config/database')
const controllerAdmin = require('../../controllers/Administration')
const controlleruser = require('../../controllers/Alliances')
router.get('/Administration/Alliances', (req, res) => controllerAdmin.findcidade3(connection, req, res))
router.get('/Administration/Alliances/limitado', (req, res) => controlleruser.findAlianca(connection, req, res))


module.exports = app => app.use('/', router)
```

models aliance

const find = (connection,username) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          connection.query(`SELECT alianca.nome,alianca.N_membros,alianca.TAG FROM user INNER JOIN alianca ON user.cod_alianca=alianca.id WHERE user.username='${username}'`, (err, result) => {
                if(err){
                    reject(err)
                }else{
                    resolve(result)
                }
            })
        })
    }

```
    module.exports = {
        find
    }
```

alliance.jade

```
extends layout
block title
   .col-xs-6.col-xs-offset-3.col-sm-6.col-sm-offset-3
   .col-sm-4(style='width:76%')
    div.panel.panel-primary(style='height:50px') Alliances Page
    div.panel.panel-primary(style='height:700px')  fdssdklfsdklfjskldfjkldsjfl
      if locals.user.cod_alianca==null
         p You Dont Have Alliances
      else 
         br
         span Your Aliance
         span= locals.Allianca.nome
   .col-xs-2.panel-red(style='width:24%;height:100%;text-align:center')
```

my app

```
require('./routes/Administration/Alliances')(app)
```

my connection db

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const config = require( "./config.json" )
const connection =mysql.createConnection({
 host:config.host,
 user:config.user,
 password:config.password,
 database:config.database,
// port:config.port
});

connection.connect((err) =>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
        process.exit(0)
    }else{
    console.log('database on')
}
})
```

what i doing wrong i can´t find the solution for my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the soluction for my problem

```
const express = require('express')
    const router = express.Router()
    const connection = require('../../Config/database')
    const controllerAdmin = require('../../controllers/Administration')
    const controlleruser = require('../../controllers/Alliances')

    router.get('/Administration/Alliances', (req, res, next) => {
        //Do something here and to add data to your request use
      controllerAdmin.findcidade3(connection, req, res)
        next();
    }, (req, res, next) => {
        //Can continue this cycle of calling next function until last `sendResponse` function is reached.
        //Can even set `error` in request for `sendResponse`
      controlleruser.findAlianca(connection, req, res)
    })
   module.exports = app => app.use('/', router)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking however if you want to call multiple function in same route/API you can do following:

Using expressJs you can use `next` function like:

```
app.get('/Administration/Alliances', (req, res, next) => { 
    //Do something here and to add data to your request use
    req.body.newData = 'newData';
    //after this just call next function
    next();
}, (req, res, next) => {
    //Can continue this cycle of calling next function until last `sendResponse` function is reached.
    //Can even set `error` in request for `sendResponse` 
    req.error = "Some error";
    next();
}, (req, res) => {
    if(req.error) {
        res.status(400).send(req.error);
    } else {
        res.status(200).send(req.body.result);
    }
});
```

Comment: i gonna ty its gonna be like this app.get('/Administration/Alliances', (req, res, next) => {
    req.body.newData = 'newData';
    next();
}, (req, res, next) => {
controllerAdmin.findcidade3(connection, req, res));
controlleruser.findAlianca(connection, req, res));
    req.error = "Some error";
    next();
}, (req, res) => {
    if(req.error) {
        res.status(400).send(req.error);
    } else {
        res.status(200).send(req.body.result);
    }
});

Comment: call `next` function from your callback function to an async function, like:

    function makeDbCall (req, res, next) {
        //make db call. 
        db.query('select query')
        .then ( result => {
             req.body.result = result;
             next();
        })
        .catch( err => {
             req.error = err;
             next();
        });
    }
    app.get('/Administration/Alliances', makeDbCall, otherFunction, responseFunction);

Comment: Can you put all chance i have to make

Comment: please share code, so i can help you better. I'm not able to understand what you are looking for. all these (req, res, next) are your functions

Comment: Got it. You see router.get('/Administration/Alliances', (req, res) => controllerAdmin.findcidade3(connection, req, res)); You dont need (req, res) => as you are doing nothing in this function just calling controllerAdmin.findcidade3 . Also I would like you to notice while calling controllerAdmin.findcidade3 you are passing 3 arguments connection, req, res, however your (req, res) => function only got 2 arguments so your res in `findcidade3` is `undefined`. This should be like router.get('/Administration/Alliances', controllerAdmin.findcidade3);

Comment: Do check this out https://github.com/navinbisht1992/navinAngular/blob/master/router/index.js I was learning at that time so not perfect but solution to your query. callback function that follow app.get('/api', cb1, cb2, cb3 ...), app.post('/api', cb1, cb2, ....), app.put('/api', cb1, cb2 .....), app.delete('/api', cb1, cb2 ...) these all cb takes 3 arguments 1. request/req, 2. response/res, 3. next().  Request/res and response/res have almost same content. Third argument is used for calling next cb.

Comment: see now my gihub project this is the link https://github.com/Kammikazy/project i put all files in github

Comment: You are using findcidade from findcidade3. So call will be router.get('/Administration/Alliances', controllerAdmin.findcidade3);  const findcidade3 = async (req,  res, next) => {    and const cidade = await Cidade.findcidade(req, req.session.user.username)  and im not able to understand what you want to do with this `res.render('Administration/Alliances')` if you want to send response here then use res.send("Your message" or JSON object);

Comment: yes exactly like that. you can set http statusCode too like res.status(200).send(req.locals.cidade); or you can just res.status(200).send(cidade);

Comment: then you need to render a HTML page and should call this API from page using Ajax call or other ways.

Comment: can you make a simple example using my code where i use multiples methods and  use ajax if  possibel can you give your skype our talk in this chat

Comment: i new using nodejs if see my project i made alot of progress but i have more to learn and thanks for your help

Comment: it have something like this  router.get('/Administration/Alliances', function (req, res, next){
controllerAdmin.findcidade3(connection, req, res);

 next()
}
, function (req, res, next) {

  controlleruser.findAlianca(connection, req, res)
 next()
 res.render('Administration/Alliances')
})

module.exports = app => app.use('/', router)

Comment: now i have the problem if the user dont have the aliance don´t work give this logs GET /vendor/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot? 304 0.278 ms - -
GET /Administration/Alliances 500 343.893 ms - 7876
undefined